# Get CKEDITOR id and value using event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

CKEDITOR 4

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
            e.editor.on('contentDom', function() {
                e.editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
                    //want current ckeditor id
                });
        });
        }); 
    });
```

I have more than one ckeditor and all are creating at run time. Is it possible to get ck editor's id and value if I have event object.

Comment: Have you looked here? http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor

Comment: yes, I tried CKEDITOR.editor.id function. But this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which version so I'm assuming 4.x. You could loop through the instances to find the document:

```
e.editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
    for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[name];
        if (instance.document == this) {
            alert('ID: ' + instance.id + '\nName: ' + instance.name + '\n' + instance.getData());
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I ran a test and the event object does have an editor property but it is undefined!? So I updated the post to find the CKEditor based on the document which is available on keyup.